# Search for records in a dataset in C#

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, combobox, textbox

I am trying to set it up so that a user may search for a specific record in a datagridview by entering details into text boxes and combo boxes. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace RRAS
{
    public partial class formRRAS : Form
    {
        public OleDbConnection DataConnection = new OleDbConnection();


        public formRRAS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void formRRAS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.tblReject_test' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tblReject_testTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tblReject_test);

        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //This creates the String Publisher which grabs the information from the combo box on the form.
            //Select and Dataconnection are also defined here.
            string Select = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test";
                string Department = txtDepartment.Text;
                string Start_Date = txtStart.Text;
                string End_Date = txtEnd.Text;
                string Anatomy = txtAnatomy.Text;
                string RFR = cmbRFR.Text;
                string Comment = txtComment.Text;

            //Select defines what should be loaded on to the dataset.
            if (Department != "")
            {
                Select = Select + " WHERE department_id =" + "'" + Department + "'";

                if (Anatomy != "")
                {
                    Select = Select + "AND body_part_examined =" + "'" + Anatomy + "'";

                    if (Start_Date != "")
                    {
                        Select = Select + " AND study_date =" + "'" + Start_Date + "'";

                        if (End_Date != "")
                        {
                            Select = Select + " AND study_date =" + "'" + End_Date + "'";

                            if (RFR != "")
                            {
                                Select = Select + " AND reject_category =" + "'" + RFR + "'";

                                if(Comment != "")
                                {
                                    Select = Select + " AND reject_comment =" + "'" + Comment + "'";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Select = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test";
            }
            //DataConnection connects to the database.
            string connectiontring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdb";
            DataConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectiontring);

            //The DataAdapter is the code that ensures both the data in the Select and DataConnection strings match.
            OleDbDataAdapter rdDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Select, DataConnection);

            try
            {
                //It then clears the datagridview and loads the data that has been selected from the DataAdapter.
                database1DataSet.tblReject_test.Clear();
                rdDataAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tblReject_test);
            }
            catch (OleDbException exc)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnLoadChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                string connectiontring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdb";
                DataConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectiontring);

                try
                {
                    int count = database1DataSet.Tables["tblReject_test"].Rows.Count;

                    DataConnection.Open();
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                    command.Connection = DataConnection;
                    string query = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test";
                    command.CommandText = query;

                    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        charRejections.Series["RFR"].Points.AddXY(reader["reject_category"].ToString(), reader[count].ToString());
                    }

                    DataConnection.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the program does search for records, to a point. It will only search for records in the order of the if statements. So I can't enter details into department as and then RFR. If I did the datagridview would only update to show me all of the records for the department I entered, it would ignore the information I entered into RFR.

Comment: you load all your data at the start this.tblReject_testTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tblReject_test); <-- Is this intentional? If so, then you may not want to make a trip to your DB evetry time but filter in memory. If you set up your data bindings using designer (you have a bindingsource bound to datagridview), then you can do: string filter = "Anatomy LIKE '%" + someText + "%'"; this.tblReject_testBindingSource.Filter = filter; <-- and youy DGV will refresh. This is much faster and no SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is not the best approach, but you could consider using something like:

```
    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                //This creates the String Publisher which grabs the information from the combo box on the form.
                //Select and Dataconnection are also defined here.

                    //here you can check if the textbox.Text is empty and if it is use the % char to match anything
                    string Department = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDepartment.Text)? "%" : txtDepartment.Text;
                    string Start_Date = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStart.Text)? "%": txtStart.Text;
                    string End_Date = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEnd.Text)? "%" : txtEnd.Text;
                    string Anatomy = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAnatomy.Text)? "%":txtAnatomy.Text;
                    string RFR = String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbRFR.Text)? "%" : cmbRFR.Text;
                    string Comment = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtComment.Text)? "%":txtComment.Text;

            //the query could look like this:
                   string Select = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test WHERE department_id LIKE '" +Department +"'" + "AND body_part_examined like'" + Anatomy +"'"+"AND study_date like'"+ Start_Date +"'";//and so on
           //rest of the code
    }
```

In the `select` we use the `'%'` wildcard if one of the textboxes didn't contain any text.

If any of the textboxes didn't contain any text, that field will be "ignored" in the query by returning any value for that column. If all textboxes are null, the query will return all the values from the `tblReject_test` table.

Also, please be aware of **[SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**.

Comment: After having to go through a number of errors of me missing quotation marks, it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do not put your ifs in that cascade way. Try something like this:

```
string Select = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test";
string Department = txtDepartment.Text;
string Start_Date = txtStart.Text;
string End_Date = txtEnd.Text;
string Anatomy = txtAnatomy.Text;
string RFR = cmbRFR.Text;
string Comment = txtComment.Text;
List<string> parameters = new List<string>();
bool first = true;

if (Department != "")
    parameters.Add("department_id =" + "'" + Department + "'");

if (Anatomy != "")
    parameters.Add("body_part_examined =" + "'" + Anatomy + "'");

if (Start_Date != "")
    parameters.Add("study_date =" + "'" + Start_Date + "'");

if (End_Date != "")
    parameters.Add("study_date =" + "'" + End_Date + "'");

if (RFR != "")
    parameters.Add("reject_category =" + "'" + RFR + "'");

if (Comment != "")
    parameters.Add("reject_comment =" + "'" + Comment + "'");

if (parameters.Count == 0)
    Select = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test";

for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count(); i++)
{ 
    if(i == 0)
        Select += " WHERE ";
    else
        Select += " AND ";
    Select += parameters[i];
}
```